# PutSQL Failed to update database due to a failed batch update. How to resolve?

Tags: sql, postgresql, apache-nifi

I'm using Nifi-1.12.1, postgresql-12.4 and java-1.8.
My flow is ListSFTP--> FetchSFTP-->MergeContent-->CountText-->ReplaceText-->PutSQL
PutSQL is a Nifi processor that I want to use to put my data into postgresql but Ihave a error in PutSQL.

```
PutSQL[id=c47b762a-1000-59c4-a833d62c53d3] Failed to update database due to a failed batch update, Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO mytable(filecount, linecount) VALUES(539, 471557) was aborted:ERROR: syntaxerroe at or near ";"
Position 52 call getNextException to see other errorsin the batch. There were a total of 1 Flowfiles that succeeded, and 0 that were not execute and will be routed to retry;;java.sql.BatchUpdateException:Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO mytable(filecount, linecount) VALUES(539, 471557) was aborted:ERROR: syntaxerroe at or near ";"
Position 52 call getNextException to see other errorsin the batch
```

[image][[image]][image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIU8P.png)
.

Comment: To troubleshot - add a `UpdateAttribute`  before `PutSQL` which will derive sql query and assign this attribute to `SQL Statement` property of `PutSQL`. Try any sql statement generated by `UpdateAttribute`  to manually run using `pgadmin`

Comment: Also, stop the PutSQL and run the rest of the flow - view the contents of the FlowFiles in the queue before PutSQL - do they all look the same?

Comment: Hi Vikramsinh Shinde, I added the UpdateAttribute processor but the error still persists. But I could not install the postgresql GUI. I am on a remote server. How can I configure UpdateAttribute?

Comment: Hi Sdairs, In my task, I collect the data and then I count the number of files collected and the number of rows in those files that I want to store in postgresql. When I run the processors and I check view the contents of the last processors before PutSQL I find the values (539, 471557).

Comment: The error you are getting is a syntax error from PostgreSQL. How are you forming the SQL query used by PutSQL processor? If not sensitive data then can you add it to the question please?

Comment: eg.  add a property `sql.stmt` to `UpdateAttribute` and deriving its value as `sql.stmt` = `insert into your_pg_table ( line_count ) values ( ${text.line.count})` and use this in `PutSQL`  by setting `SQL Statement` = `${sql.stmt}`

Comment: Hi Vikramsinh Shinde, I have attached the configuration of the PutSQL and UpdateAttribute processors.
the SQL query that I had put in the PutSQL processor
SQL Statement= INSERT INTO mytable(filecount, linecount) VALUES(${merge.count}, ${text.line.count})

Comment: I can see `PutSQL` state is INVALID, can you please  make sure that PG Controller Service is running? Also try by changing - put insert values in single quotes like, `INSERT INTO mytable(filecount, linecount) VALUES('${merge.count}', '${text.line.count}') `

Comment: Hi Vikramsinh Shine, thanks for your help. the processor PutSQL is running now.